# Cors problems with Html2canvas loading images from Laravel public storage

Tags: php, laravel, apache, cpanel, html2canvas

I'm trying to grab a piece of HTML that has images stored in Laravel's public storage. The images show up fine on my page, but when I use html2canvas to export, it throws a CORS error. It's saying something about the Access-Control-Origins header missing in the images.

Just so you know, the images load without any issue on my website, but exporting with html2canvas causes CORS errors. My Laravel API is on a shared hosting with cPanel.
My export function is this:

```
async function captureScreenshot() {
  if (cardRef.value) {
    const canvas = await html2canvas(cardRef.value);
    const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    // Create a temporary link for downloading the image
    const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.href = dataUrl;
    downloadLink.download = entry.uuid + '.png';
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
  }
}
```

I tried different .htaccess files to make the server include that header, but no luck fixing it.